# aggregate -> getting error "not meaningful for factors" after switch from 2.15 to 3.1.0

Tags: r

Im running win7 32bit verson of R with recent Rstudio.

I have a bunch (lots of) inherited code written within 2.15 version of R.

After installing new R codes broke down, but i was unable to understand why. It looks like some functions (aggregate.fromula ?) were redesigned?

Example:
lets say we have a data.frame  DATA (consits of serial number, USD_BAL, Clientname)

in 2.15 this action:

```
TEST_AGG <- aggregate(czk_balance ~ ico_topaz + branch,
                      data = DATA[DATA$USD_BAL <= 0,],
                      sum,  
                      na.rm=T)
```

yields desired result.

however when run in 3.1.0 i get smt like:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(DATA$USD_BAL, 0) : <= not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(DATA$USD_BAL, 0) : <= not meaningful for factors
```

Please, is there any clear solution what to change in order to make it work with the new R?

Comment: It seems that `DATA$USD_BAL` is a factor, therefore, logical operations such `DATA$USD_BAL <= 0` is not allowed and you're getting the message `...<= not meaningful for factors...`. Your error is in `DATA[DATA$USD_BAL <= 0,]` not in using `aggregate` itself.

Comment: Looks like your column USD_BAL is a factor. Have you checked the class? by doing `sapply(DATA,class)` or done `str(DATA)`.

Comment: thanks for answer. Also I havent changed the parts of formula in the example but it does not matter now. Question is: why the R 2.15 takes it ok and 3.1.0 does not? sorry im only 1 month long R user so far
thanks for all answers so far!

i just checked with str(DATA) and they are indeed all factors

Comment: I checked in 2.15 now, in that version the USD_BAL has a class of NUM, in 3.1.0 it is Factor, which is weird. None of the code is changed. The data itself is got from SQL database through RODBC package

Comment: as a hack you can do this as.numeric(as.character(USD_BAL)). will have to see your code for loading the data to see why it's converting into factor

Comment: Thanks again for a very quick answer
`DATA$USD_BAL<-as.numeric(as.character(DATA$USD_BAL))`

indeed works, thanks.

question is: what might be difference between versions? This means i'll have to correct all the source codes if i wish to start using new R version (they are many,i have no one to help and i dont know them all so far)

thank u again

Comment: Data is loaded with
`library("RODBC")

channel <- odbcConnect(dsn="XYZ", uid="XXX", pwd="PASSWORD")`

`sql_select  <-       "USD_BAL etc... "`
`sql_from    <-       "from [Temp].[dbo].[TABLE] "`
`sql_where   <- paste("where [date_1] = '", as.Date(availabled[1,1]), "' and [gl_syntetic] = '123456' ", sep="")`
`DATA    <- sqlQuery(channel, paste(sql_select, sql_from, sql_where))`

none of the code is changed, only when run inder 2.15 USD_BAL is correct under 3.1.0 it is factor.

(i try to simplify as much as possible)

Comment: This seems very unlikely to be due to a change in R version. Post `dput(head(DATA))` AND the output of `options()$stringsAsFactors`from two separate sessions running the two versions. You will see that one has a numeric (or character) classed column and the other has a factor-claased column. The default in R is to make data.frames containing factors but it is possible to globally disable that with `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. R didn't change but it is possible to change R.

Comment: the only idea i got:
there is a difference in RODBC
for r 2.15 its ver 1.3.6
for r 3.1.0 its ver 1.3.10

does it make sense?

Comment: Try your code in R 3.1.0 with this stringsAsFactors=FALSE in your sqlQuery call and also try as.is=T. See if you get the same results. Finally read `?sqlQuery` in R 2.15 and R 3.10 and see whether they are different.

Comment: Hey, so i ran some further tests

R 3.1.0, RODBC 1.3-10
when using `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` i get result as character for 3 of my columns(including USD_BAL) and num for last column

when using `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and as.is=T in sqlQuery i get all columns as char. Same with as.is=T and stringasF =F

guess ill have to dig deeper into possible differences for sqlQuery(RODBC package command) to sort this out>

Anyways, all your help is much appreciated. I will try to help with simple tasks, too when i get the chance :)

Comment: so running the very same command yields 2 results in R -upper is 215(desired/current) 
i checked the help for RODBC 1.36 and 1.3.10 and i see no difference in terms of as.is (default =FALSE) or stringAsFactors=default.stringsAsFactors()

i also tried to install RODBC 1.3-6 from tar for R 3.1.0 but got some error...
i am seriously getting out of ideas

Comment: sry i forgot
[http://i61.tinypic.com/23jmll.jpg]

Comment: Finall call- tried to used RODBC 1.3.6 with r 3.1.0 but it is incompatible
also looked into changelog of RODBC versions and there is no mention about the issue

i dont like when programs work in an odd way..